# Making subgroups in Python

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list such as the following, which indicates four groups (A, B, C and D). Imagine that each element in the list indicates a person. So person 1 is in Group A, person 2 is in Group B, person 3 is in Group D, and so on.

`["A", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A"]`

The number of occurrences of each alphabet is always in multiples of 3. Notice that B and C occur thrice each, while A occurs six times.

I want to divide each of these four groups into four random subgroups. An example of the desired output:

`["A1", "B2", "D2", "C1", "B1", "C3", "A2", "B3", "A3", "C2", "A2", "D3", "A3", "D1",  "A1"]`

Here, A1 is one subgroup, which is distinct from A2 and A3. A2 is also distinct from A3. Likewise for the rest. Notice that all subgroups starting with the same alphabet must be of the same size. Hence A1, A2, and A3 have the same number of elements, but B1 can have a different number of elements as compared to A1.

Another example of the desired output (since allocation to subgroups is random):

`["A2", "B3", "D2", "C1", "B2", "C3", "A3", "B1", "A1", "C2", "A2", "D1", "A1", "D3",  "A3"]`

How can I do this?

Comment: With random do you mean *each time different*, or *I do not care how*? Can it happen that one "subgroup" has no elements (e.g. `"A3"` never occurs).

Comment: Each time different.

Comment: No. All subgroups starting with the same alphabet must be the exact same size. That is, if A1 has two elements, A2 must also have two elements. But D1 can have one element.

Comment: Hi @wwl Nice, to have you here, asking your question. But at present, I think, it might be unclear, what your question or your intention is.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to incorporate @WillemVanOnsem 's questions. If there are other parts you are unclear about, let me know!

Comment: Can the things in the array/list be sorted? Is `A < B` a valid operation?  Is `A1 == A2` True? Are you asking literally how to randomly assign sequence numbers to groups of letters?

Comment: No, they cannot be sorted. What do you mean by is A < B is valid operation?

Comment: 'A' occurs 6 times. Looking at just the 'A':s we have the permutation 2,3,1,2,1,3 in the last example.  Would it be ok to have 2,2,1,1,3,3 as valid case or do you have to permute them 3 at a time?

Comment: 2,2,1,1,3,3 is a valid case, but it should be equally likely as 1,3,2,1,3,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will generate random subgroups where each subgroup of a given character is the same size; i.e., where for the provided list, where there were six elements of the primary group `A`, there are exactly two elements of `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` respectively. Similarly, for each other primary group of size three, there is exactly one element in each subgroup in the final output.

```
from collections import Counter
from random      import randint

element_counter = Counter()

n = 3 # The number of subgroups to produce: the LCM of the size of each group.

groups = ["A", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A"]

# Counts the number of elements in each group.
for element in groups:

    element_counter[element] += 1

subscripts = {key : None for key in element_counter}

# Produces a list of possible subscripts: e.g., [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
# such that each subgroup of a given group is the same size.
for key in element_counter:

    size = element_counter[key]

    subscripts[key] = [x for x in range(1, n + 1) for y in range(size // n)]

subgroups = []

# Draws and removes a random subscript from the list of subscripts for each
# group member to generate the subgroups.
for element in groups:

    random_number = randint(0, len(subscripts[element]) - 1)

    subgroups.append("{}{}".format(element, subscripts[element].pop(random_number)))

print("Before:\t{}".format(groups))
print("After:\t{}".format(subgroups))
```

---

**Sample output:**

Run 1:

```
Before: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A']
After:  ['A2', 'B3', 'D3', 'C1', 'B2', 'C2', 'A1', 'B1', 'A3', 'C3', 'A2', 'D2', 'A1', 'D1', 'A3']
```

Run 2:

```
Before: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A']
After:  ['A3', 'B3', 'D3', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1', 'A3', 'B1', 'A2', 'C3', 'A2', 'D1', 'A1', 'D2', 'A1']
```

Run 3:

```
Before: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A']
After:  ['A1', 'B1', 'D3', 'C2', 'B3', 'C3', 'A2', 'B2', 'A3', 'C1', 'A3', 'D1', 'A2', 'D2', 'A1']
```

Answer (score 1):

A simlar, but somewhat more compact solution.

```
#! /usr/bin/env/python3
"""
Count the occurence of each symbol.  Each symbols occurs M times, make
a list of the first M integers and store the symbol and the list in a
dictionary.  This is the group.

Randomly permute each group and create a new temporary dictionary that
contains the mod of N for each group element.  Iterate over the
original sequence and concate the two giving the result, popping
element from the temporary dictionary.

"""
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

N = 3
seq = ["A", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A"]

symbol = Counter(seq)
group = {key: list(range(count)) for key, count in symbol.items()}

# Do some shuffling
for s in range(10):
    for element_group in group.values():
        shuffle(element_group)
    tmp_shuffle = {k: [e % N + 1 for e in g] for k, g in group.items()}
    grouped_seq = [e + str(tmp_shuffle[e].pop()) for e in seq]

    print(grouped_seq)
```

Sample output from a run:

```
['A3', 'B3', 'D2', 'C2', 'B1', 'C1', 'A3', 'B2', 'A2', 'C3', 'A1', 'D3', 'A1', 'D1', 'A2']
['A3', 'B3', 'D3', 'C1', 'B2', 'C2', 'A3', 'B1', 'A2', 'C3', 'A1', 'D2', 'A2', 'D1', 'A1']
['A2', 'B1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B3', 'C3', 'A3', 'B2', 'A1', 'C2', 'A3', 'D3', 'A1', 'D1', 'A2']
['A1', 'B2', 'D1', 'C1', 'B1', 'C2', 'A3', 'B3', 'A2', 'C3', 'A3', 'D2', 'A1', 'D3', 'A2']
['A1', 'B3', 'D2', 'C3', 'B2', 'C2', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'C1', 'A2', 'D1', 'A1', 'D3', 'A3']
['A2', 'B1', 'D1', 'C3', 'B3', 'C2', 'A3', 'B2', 'A1', 'C1', 'A1', 'D3', 'A3', 'D2', 'A2']
['A2', 'B1', 'D1', 'C1', 'B3', 'C3', 'A2', 'B2', 'A3', 'C2', 'A1', 'D3', 'A1', 'D2', 'A3']
['A2', 'B3', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'C2', 'A3', 'D3', 'A1', 'D1', 'A1']
['A1', 'B3', 'D3', 'C2', 'B2', 'C1', 'A3', 'B1', 'A2', 'C3', 'A3', 'D1', 'A1', 'D2', 'A2']
['A3', 'B2', 'D1', 'C3', 'B1', 'C1', 'A3', 'B3', 'A2', 'C2', 'A1', 'D2', 'A1', 'D3', 'A2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you wanted to do, but this script assigns every character from the array to a different subgroup. You can test it here: https://repl.it/NkQK/0

```
subcats = [1, 2, 3]
dic = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0}

arr = ["A", "B", "D", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A"]


for x in arr:
  dic[x] = dic[x]+1


for i in range(len(arr)):
  temp = dic[arr[i]] - 1
  if (dic[arr[i]] > len(subcats)):
    temp = dic[arr[i]] % len(subcats) - 1

  dic[arr[i]] = int(dic[arr[i]]) - 1
  arr[i] = arr[i] + str(subcats[temp])

print(arr)
```